# Insert arrays into HTML element

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fairly new to PHP, but i have ended up messing around with arrays.

I have this structure, and alot of them:

```
  ["ugedage"]=>
array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "Mandag (14/8)"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "Tirsdag (15/8)"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "Onsdag (16/8)"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "Torsdag (17/8)"
    [4]=>
    string(13) "Fredag (18/8)"
  }
```

The code initiating all this looks like this:

```
$skema['ugedage'] = array();
```

I have tried this as of now (this doesnt return anything, but leaves the the div empty!):

```
<div class="test"><?php echo $skema['ugedage'][4]; ?></div>
```

I'm including the file (lectio.php) in the index.php this way:

```
        <?php
    include("lectio/lectio.php");
        $lectio = new lectio();
        $skemamag = $lectio->get_skema_til_elev(94, 16305782848);
var_dump($skemamag); ?>

$skemamag
```

Is outputting all the arrays for that specific ids.

EDIT:
The whole public function, it goes into a student platform and search for elements on a students schedule. The idea is to make the arrays appear with an element around, so it would be possible to style the specific array.

```
    public function get_skema($url_til_skema)
{
    $lectio_html = $this->get_content($url_til_skema);
    $skema = array(); //Definer skema variabel til return værdi!
    $skema['titel'] = ''; //Definer struktur for titel
    $skema['ugedage'] = array(); //Definer struktur for liste over ugedage
    $skema['dagskema'] = array(); //Definer struktur for dagskemaet
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($lectio_html);
    $skema['titel'] = $html->find('.s2weekHeader td', 0)->plaintext; //Hent overskriften uden html (uge og år)
    $headers = $html->find('.s2dayHeader td'); //Søg efter listen over dage i det pågældende skema 
    for($i=1;$i<count($headers);$i++) //Bemærk vi starter i = 1 fordi vi springer den første over (altid tom)
    {
        $skema['ugedage'][] = $headers[$i]->plaintext; //Tilføj alle overskrifterne på ugedagene (uden html)
        $skema['dagskema'][$headers[$i]->plaintext] = array(
            'noter' => array(),
            'fag' => array()
            ); //Tilføj en struktur til nøglen for hvert dagskema
    }
    $collection = $html->find('.s2skemabrikcontainer'); //Søg efter den ydre skema container for hver dag
    /*
    BEMÆRK!!!! 
    Den ydre skema container, der er langt flere end antal dage. Feks. kan en uge med 5 dage
    have 11 ydre containere pga. 5 til moduler, 5 til "noter" i toppen, og én til sidebaren.
    */
    $skemabrik = new simple_html_dom(); //Definer den her for genbrugens skyld da den kan tømmes efter hver iteration
    for($i=0; $i<count($skema['ugedage']); $i++) //Iterer alle noterne i "toppen" af ugedagene
    {
        $skemabrik->load($collection[$i]->innertext);
        $noter = $skemabrik->find('.s2skemabrikcontent');
        foreach($noter as $note)
        {
            //Tilføj til liste over noter for dagen
            $skema['dagskema'][$skema['ugedage'][$i]]['noter'][] = trim(html_entity_decode($note->plaintext));
        }
    }
    //Iterer alle fagene/noterne i selve skemaet for hver dag
    //Vi starter iteratoren i count($skema['ugedage']) + 1 fordi vi vil springe topnoter + et stil element i mellem over.
    for($i=count($skema['ugedage'])+1; $i<(2*count($skema['ugedage'])+1); $i++) 
    {
        $skemabrik->load($collection[$i]->innertext);
        $noter = $skemabrik->find('.s2skemabrikcontent');
        foreach($noter as $note)
        {
            //Tilføj til dagskemaet
            $skema['dagskema'][$skema['ugedage'][$i-count($skema['ugedage'])-1]]['fag'][] = array(
                'tekst' => trim(html_entity_decode($note->plaintext)),
                'note' => ''
                );
        }
    }
    for($i=5; $i<count($skema['ugedage'])+6; $i++) //Gennemgå alle dagene
    {
        $skemabrik->load($collection[$i]->innertext); //Indlæs hver dag
        $skemabrik_elementer = $skemabrik->find('.s2skemabrik'); //Søg efter alle skemabrikkerne på denne dag
        for($y=0; $y<count($skemabrik_elementer); $y++) //Gennemgå alle noterne til hvert fag/note/whatever
        {
            //Tilføj noten til det korrekte fag 
            $skema['dagskema'][$skema['ugedage'][$i-6]]['fag'][$y]['note']=trim(html_entity_decode($skemabrik_elementer[$y]->title));
        }
    }
    return $skema;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your question, it's unclear what output you're expecting to see. For example, you reference index `5` of the subarray but you're only showing the subarray as having been initialized for indices `0` through `4`.

Comment: That's a typo, it's been fixed now.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? try throw more light on it. You could easily use a loop and avoid putting wrong indexes

Comment: I have posted the whole public function on the post. There is alot more arrays, and as it scraps through the html on the external page, it works and gets the correct data. I just somehow wants to be able to put  each array into an HTML element so it can be styled later on.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard "This doesnt return anything. The div is just purely empty". Please edit this info from your comment to ishegg's answer into your question.  This is an important piece of information ;)

Comment: @faintsignal Consider it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting an out of bounds error. In most programming languages (PHP included), array [indices start at 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). So to get that last element, you need number 4:

```
<div class="test"><?php echo $skema['ugedage'][4]; ?></div>
```

Comment: This doesnt return anything. The div is just purely empty. It's very weird to be honest, as i read alot of answers about it

Comment: Can you post the lines where you add the elements to the $skema array?

Comment: I will add the whole public function to the post, as it might give more sense. This issue applies to all arrays made in this code.

Comment: I can’t comment in other answers yet. Can you post the code where you call the function? I’m guessing maybe you’re trying to access the $skema variable from outside the function but since its scope is inside the function, you’re not seeing anything. Are you assigning get_schema() to a variable named $skema also? Also, try enabling PHP printing errors to the screen so you can see more information about what’s wrong.

Comment: check my question - this line: <div class="test"><?php echo $skema['ugedage'][4]; ?></div>, is where i call it in the index.php file - my updated answer include how i include the code file etc. Check it out.

Comment: You seem to be calling a different method? It’s not called get_skema()

Comment: What do you mean? get_skema is the public function, in which the arrays are created/scrapped/what you want to call it. :) What should i be calling if thats the right one?

Comment: In the code you pasted, you call the function get_skema_til_elev(), not get_schema() which is the one you showed us here.

Comment: ishegg - get_skem_til_elev is just outputting all the data in general, including the arrays posted. But all the methods behind it, is in the get_skema function

Comment: That actually made it! Thank you - is it possible to only display half a string or some parts of it (in an array?)

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard I'm not quite sure what happened but I'm glad you got it working :). About your other question, you should post a new question to keep matters organized!

Comment: can i message you anywhere?